Problems of removing and redrawing the overlays after applying for leaflet.greatCircle.js
the layers remained

I am running a small web project using Open Street Map using leaflet.
Since OSM doesn't take earth's curvature into account. It drew a simple straight polyline.
I found leaflet.greatCircle.js on the internet and applied to my twilight overlays and measurement functions
However the layers are not removed properly causing them to keep stacking up each other
I asked gpt to find out what the problem is, and I am replied to modify removing and redrawing layers. I followed its suggestions however the issue persists.

changed the handling of removing and redrawing functions after chatgpt solutions
remove: function () {
    if (this._polygon) this._polygon.remove();
    if (this._circle) this._circle.remove();
    if (typeof this._circles !== "undefined") {
        if (this._circles.length > 0) {
            for (var i in this._circles) {
                this._circles[i].remove();
            }
        }
        this._circles = undefined;
    }
    this._addedToMap = false;
},

